# How to know if a module is defined in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby it's easy to see if a module is defined:

```
defined? MyModule
```

But in Rails, when you do that Rails tries to load the module (from autoload paths, etc.). So if it does not exists, it throws an error instead of returning `false`.

I could do

```
do
  defined? MyModule
rescue
  # false
end
```

But it there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ruby and Rails are you using? When I try this, no error is thrown:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :1 > defined? Rails
 => "constant" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :2 > defined? NotAConstant
 => nil
```

Comment: Are you doing that is a Rails console ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise Rails wouldn't be defined. ;)